# How to implement hashCode() in Swift for use by NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, swift, hashcode

I'm trying to use a Swift object as a key in an NSMutableDictionary.  I've implemented hashValue and equality as usual and it works in a native Swift dict.  But NSMutableDictionary never calls my hash function.  What am I missing?

```
public final class Holder : Hashable, NSCopying
{
    var val : Int = 0
    public init( _ val : Int ) { self.val = val }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return val
    }

    @objc public func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        return self
    }
}

public func == (lhs: Holder, rhs: Holder) -> Bool {
    return lhs.val==rhs.val
}

//var dict = Dictionary<Holder,String>()
var dict = NSMutableDictionary()

dict[ Holder(42) ]="foo"
dict[ Holder(42) ] // NSMutableDictionary will not call my hash function, returns nil here.
```

ANSWER:

I had to implement explicitly hash() and isEqual() like so:

```
@objc public func hash() -> Int {
    return hashValue
}

@objc public func isEqual( obj : AnyObject ) -> Bool {
    return (obj as? Holder)?.val == val
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary uses the [`hash` and `isEqual` methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash) from NSObjectProtocol:

```
@objc var hash: Int { return hashValue }
@objc func isEqual(o: AnyObject?) -> Bool { return o as? Holder == self }

// ...

dict[ Holder(42) ] = "foo"
dict[ Holder(42) ] // returns "foo"
```

However, if possible I would recommend sticking with a Swift dictionary `[Holder:String]`, as you tried previously.

Comment: Thanks.  You posted just as I was answering my own question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the motivation for putting a Swift object in a NSMutableDictionary? I would recommend using Swift Dictionary instead. If you really do want it to be used in NSDictionary, you probably should inherit from NSObject.

Comment: It was an experiment to compare the performance characteristics.